# python multithread logic hole

Tags: python, multithreading

I can't think of a solution to this logic problem in python multithreading

Each thread created does this:

1. wait on condition variable C1
2. Do the required work
3. decrement a counter NT using a lock Lnt to keep threads from overwriting
4. if NT decrements to zero signal condition variable C2
5. )loop back to waiting on C1

The main thread does this:

1. set counter NT to the number of threads waiting on C1
2. release all threads waiting on C1
3. wait on C2
4. process work done by the threads
5. get things ready for the next iteration
6. loop back to step 1

The hole is the threads could all finish before the main thread has a chance to block on C2.  Not a likely event, but it could happen. If this does happen, the main thread will be blocked forever. A messy solution is for the main thread to do a non-blocking wait and check the counter. I want a cleaner solution. But I can't think of one.

Comment: You have explained how the threads interact with C1. How are the threads interacting with C2 ? Is a condition variable the most appropriate synchronizing object to be using when you are interested in the number of threads running?

Comment: C2 allows the main thread to wait for all the other threads to finish. When the last thread decrements the counter to zero, it signals C2, releasing the main thread.

Comment: Basically, you have a bunch of threads doing some background work, right? Can you write the code that allows you to create one worker thread that does a single job? You can then extend that to multiple jobs done by one thread in the first step and multiple jobs done by multiple threads in the second step. That said, an event can be signalled before(!) anyone is waiting on it, I believe.

Comment: Actually, it's heavy computation, one iteration done linearly will take 1.20 seconds. But I have to iterate the process thousands of times. The normal way of calling start and join for the threads adds too much overhead.

Comment: Have you done any testing on this? To test it - start the threads from the main thread. Put the main thread to sleep for a few seconds while the thread finish and then let it access C2. What happens? Can you put C2 so that it blocks automatically? You can then release the threads when 'main' access it? A 'counting semaphore' will do what you want. Or, have the 'main' thread check the 'active' count before accessing C2 (using locks).

Comment: Another way of doing this is to have two queues of 'workers' (threads) 1) 'active' threads. 2) 'Waiting'  threads. The 'main' thread manages the queues. The threads put themselves in the 'Waiting' queue when the have completed the current task. The main tasks starts all the 'workers' then waits on the 'Waiting' queue and starts 'em again as required.

Comment: Extra information that may be useful ... please see: [does-or-doesnt-python-support-multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939299/does-or-doesnt-python-support-multithreading?rq=1)

Comment: OK, I thought there was something I was missing. All you have to do to close the probability gap is the main thread must acquire C2 before doing the C1.notifyAll(), Then it does a C2.wait(). That way the worker threads can't notify C2 before the main thread is waiting.

Comment: Excellent, glad you sorted it out. May be worth while posting that as an answer? You can accept your own answers. That way people know the question is 'solved'.

Answer (score 0):

all worker threads are created at the start of the program and never destroyed

```
def worker():
    global c1,c2,nt,lnt
    while true:
        c1.acquire()
        c1.wait()
        c1.release()

        Do the computations

        lnt.acquire()
        nt -= 1
        if nt == 0:
            c2.acquire()
            c2.notify()
            c2.release()
        lnt.release()

def main():
    for i in range(100000):
        c2.acquire()
        nt = numthreads
        c1.acquire()
        c1.notifyAll()
        c1.release()
        c2.wait()
        c2.release()
        process  computed data
```