# Controlling CPU Usage and Threading In Python

Tags: python, multithreading, cpu-usage

I'm running a computation heavy program in Python that takes about 10 minutes to run on my system. When I look at CPU usage, one of eight cores is hovering at about 70%, a second is at about 20%, and the rest are close to 0%.Is there any way I can force the program into 100% usage of a single core?

edit: I recognize that utilizing all 8 cores isn't a great option, but is there a way to force the one core into 100% usage?

Comment: Python is single threaded.

Comment: if there is it wouldn't be specific to python, it'd be for your operating system which you have not mentioned.

Comment: This question has an answer that may interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939299/does-python-support-multithreading-can-it-speed-up-execution-time

Answer (score 1):

For multi-core applications you should use the `multiprocessing` module instead of `threading`. Python has some (well documented) performance issues with threads. Search google for Global Interpreter Lock for more information about Python and thread performance

Answer (score 0):

Python isn't really multithreaded. You can create threads as a convenient way to manage logical processes, but the application itself has a [global thread lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Because of this, you'll only ever be able to utilize a single thread.

You can use a different flavor of python, but that may provide you with other issues. If you're willing to break it out into distinct processes, you may be able to utilize the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. This creates two distinct python processes, but they can operate independently. Unfortunately, you'll have to code a method by which they communicate.