# Python: Parallel distance calculation in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

I've a data frame for which I want to calculate the distance of each row to every other row. I need it to be very fast of course so I added some parallelism. But I see that it runs faster with a single thread for some reason.

```
dist = {}
dist_lock = threading.Lock()


def calculate_dist_threaded(data_frame, num_threads):
// calculate set of indexes for each thread, store in indexes array.

tuple_data_frame = list(data_frame.itertuples())

r = [None]
for attr in list(data_frame):
    if data_frame[attr].dtype in ['int32', 'float64']:
        dft = data_frame[attr][data_frame[attr] != sys.maxint].dropna()
        r.append(dft.max() - dft.min())
    else:
        r.append(None)

for i in range(data_frame.shape[0]):
    dist[i] = {}

// run each calculate_dist for each thread.


def calculate_dist(tuples, indexes, r):
    for i in indexes:
        logger.debug("working on index={0}".format(i))
        for other in tuples:
            if other[0] in dist[i]:
                continue
            if i == other[0]:
                d = 0.0
            else:
                d = dist_tuples(tuples[i], other, r)
            with dist_lock:
                dist[i][other[0]] = d
                dist[other[0]][i] = d

def dist_tuples(x, y, r):
   d = 0.0
   for i in range(1, len(x)):
        if x[i] == y[i]:
            d += 0.0
        elif isinstance(x[i], numbers.Number):
            d += abs(x[i] - y[i]) / r[i]
        else:
            d += 1.0
   return d


if __name__ == "__main__":
     calculate_dist_threaded(data, multiprocessing.cpu_count())
```

When I run it with 4 threads as it is the number of cpus on my laptop I see that it takes 15 seconds to calculate for 4 separate indexes at the same time.
But if I run the same code with just one thread I see that it takes just 2 seconds to calculate for a single index so it's almost 2 seconds faster than with 4 threads.
Am I missing something and have a blocking piece of code here or is just my lame laptop?

Comment: Threading in Python will usually decrease performance for CPU bound tasks due to the global interpreter lock.  Consider [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) or potentially [`dask`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html).  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939299/does-python-support-multithreading-can-it-speed-up-execution-time?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: you are using loops - that makes your calculations slow. Please provide  small (5-7 rows) sample reproducible data set in text/CSV form and desired data set. What distance metric are you using - euclidean, cosine, haversine, something else? Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)