# Python multithreading function argument

Tags: python, concurrency

I was writing some multithreading code and had a syntax issue in my code and found that the code was not executing in parallel but rather sequentially. I fixed the issue to pass the arguments to the function as a separate list instead of passing it as a parameter to the function but I couldn't figure out why python was behaving that way and couldn't find documentation for it. Anyone know why?

```py
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def do_work(i):
    print("{} {} - Command started".format(i, time.time()))
    time.sleep(1)

count = 0
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
while count < 5:
    print("Starting work")
    executor.submit(do_work(count))
    print("Work submitted")
    count += 1
```

Fixed this line to make it go parallel.

```
    executor.submit(do_work, count)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were telling Python to execute the function `do_work()`, and to then pass whatever that function returned, to `executor.do_work()`:

```
executor.submit(do_work(count))
```

It might be easier for you to see this if you used a variable to hold the result of `do_work()`. The following is functionally equivalent to the above:

```
do_work_result = do_work(count)
executor.submit(do_work_result)
```

In Python, functions are first-class objects; using just the name `do_work` you are referencing the function object. Only adding `(...)` to an expression that produces a function object (or another callable object type) causes something to be executed.

In the form

```
executor.submit(do_work, count)
```

you do *not* call the function. You are passing in the function object itself as the first argument, and `count` as the second argument. The `executor.submit()` function accepts callable objects and their arguments to then *later on* run those functions in parallel, with the arguments provided.

This allows the `ThreadPoolExecutor` to take that function reference and the single argument and only call the function in a new thread, *later on*.

Because you were calling the function first, you had to wait for each function to complete first as you called it sequentially before adding. And because the functions return `None`, you were adding those `None` references to `executor.submit()`, and would have seen a `TypeError` exception *later on* to tell you that `'NoneType' object is not callable`. That happens because the threadpool executor tried to use `None()`, which doesn't work because indeed, `None` is not a callable.

Under the hood, the library essentially does this:

```
def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
    # record the function to be called as a work item, with other information
    w = _WorkItem(..., fn, args, kwargs)
    self._work_queue.put(w)
```

so a work item referencing the function and arguments is added to a queue. Worker threads are created which take items from the queue again it is taken from the queue (in another thread, or a child process), the `_WorkItem.run()` method is called, which runs your function:

```
result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
```

Only *then* the `(...)` call syntax is used. Because there are multiple threads, the code is executed concurrently.

You do want to read up on how pure Python code *can't run in parallel*, only concurrently: [Does Python support multithreading? Can it speed up execution time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939299/does-python-support-multithreading-can-it-speed-up-execution-time/20939442#20939442)

Your `do_work()` functions only run 'faster' because `time.sleep()` doesn't have to do any actual work, apart from telling the kernel to not give any execution time to the thread the sleep was executed on, for the requested amount of time. You end up with a bunch of threads all asleep. If your workers had to execute Python instructions, then the total time spent on running these functions concurrently or sequentially would not differ all that much.